# Want NO ACTION on delete and NO ACTION on update on doctrine 2 ORM

Tags: zend-framework, orm, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, doctrine

I created an entity as below:

```
namespace Application\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
/**
 * Application\Entity\Example
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="example")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */

class Example {
     //...
     /**
      *
      * @var datetime 
      * @ORM\Column(name="created_at", type="datetime", nullable=false)
      */
      private $createdAt;

     /**
      *
      * @var integer 
      * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User")
      * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="created_by", referencedColumnName="iduser", onDelete="NO ACTION")
      */
      private $createdBy;

   //.........

}
```

I tried to add annotation onDelete="NO ACTION" but it does not do anything.

I want to the NO ACTION for both on Update and On Delete on MySQL. Is there any way to do such or is it not supported by doctrine 2?

Comment: What happens when you completely delete the `onDelete="NO ACTION"` from current annotations?

Comment: It retains the same RESTRICT on my db.

Comment: If I manually change my on Delete to NO ACTION from my database, it changes back to RESTRICT after orm update from CLI.

Comment: Are you creating your database using the Doctrine schema-tool? What if you once try to set `onDelete="CASCADE"` does that setting at least end up in your database?

Comment: I created my db using `php bin/doctrine.php orm:schema-tool:update --force` but I could not generate the foreign key actions. Is there any way to set NO ACTION for both update and delete?

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation of Doctrine-ORM Documentation, the attributes of [@JoinColumn](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-joincolumn) are :

- name
- referencedColumnName
- unique
- nullable
- onDelete
- columnDefinition

So, the attribute you have used here onDelete="NO ACTION" should work here. But for 'on Update', there is not such attribute defined. By default, the (onUpdate) attribute of MySQL will use "Restrict" which is a synonym of "No Action" as described [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13571/usage-of-restrict-or-no-action-in-foreign-key-constraints).

As per my information, `onUpdate` attribute was removed from Doctrine 2. I don't know the actual reason behind it. But it's fine if you don't use onUpdate and get 'ON UPDATE = Restrict' by default instead of 'ON UPDATE = No Action' as you need in your question.

Comment: But how to set ON UPDATE CASCADE?

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
  * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User")
  * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="created_by", referencedColumnName="iduser",onDelete="NO ACTION")
**/
```

and then you need to execute the command

```
>php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```